# Adding a data point attribute with `attributes` processor, but also passing through original metrics?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am using the opentelemetry collector on an EC2 instance to publish metrics to CloudWatch, using awsemf. I'm currently adding a tag for the instance ID to the metrics:

```yaml
processors:
  attributes:
    actions:
      - key: host.id
        value: "${EC2_INSTANCE_ID}"
        action: insert
  batch:
exporters:
  awsemf: # https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/awsemfexporter
    log_group_name: "${AWSEMF_LOG_GROUP_NAME}"
    log_stream_name: "${EC2_INSTANCE_ID}"
  logging:
    verbosity: normal
service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp, prometheus]
      processors: [batch, attributes]
      exporters: [awsemf, logging]
```

(EC2_INSTANCE_ID is getting injected via systemd. I could use the `resourcedetection` processor to do something similar, but that creates resource attributes, not data point attributes, and the `awsemf` exporter only sends data point attributes by default. It can send all resource attributes as data point attributes, but that creates a huge number of dimensions which make it difficult to use the CloudWatch UI.)

I'm adding this instance-id attribute because I want to be able to drill down into host level from the metrics. However, this creates a problem for setting up alarms - [they cannot have a wildcard for instance-id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502491/can-a-cloudwatch-alarm-be-defined-for-a-metric-over-many-dimensions) - so I also want to publish metrics without this attribute as well for alarms (and dashboards).

**What is the cleanest way to set up the attributes processor to add the attribute to the metrics, but also pass through the original metrics as well?** Setting up a second pipeline in parallel to the first seems somewhat wasteful of resources.

(I am aware the awsemfexporter has an `dimension_rollup_option` parameter, but it rolls up some things I don't want rolled up, and doesn't publish all combinations of tags with instance-id removed.)

Comment: I would try `routingconnector`.